# Unknown item "Nike + ipod" in Settings

Tags: ios, settings

I wish to know what the purpose of item "Nike + ipod" is in the Settings app on my iPhone?

Answer (score 1):

It's ready for you to connect to a Nike exercise wristband.
It's a core structure & can't be deleted. It's been there since about iOS 4/5.

If you update to iOS 8.2 you'll find there's a new app too, ready to connect to your shiny new Apple Watch… if you ever think of buying one…. again, a core app, can't be deleted.